# Parsing json objects only

Tags: android, json, eclipse, parsing

[image]I am having a lot of trouble with this. I have a json array that i have parsed which works great. I have another webpage for a single user i am trying to parse. here is the php. its valid json.

```
{
    "userURL": "http://forum.example.com.php?u=426561",
    "userId": "426561",
    "forumName": "example name",
    "totalPosts": "19787",
    "postsPerDay": "8.11",
    "totalThanks": "40585",
    "joinDate": "2007-02-20",
    "yearsJoined": "6",
    "referrals": "17",
    "friendCount": "61",
    "recognizedDeveloper": "1",
    "recognizedContributor": "0",
    "recognizedThemer": "0",
    "moderator": "0",
    "recognizedEliteDeveloper": "0",
    "romCount": "100",
    "kernelCount": "1",
    "tutorialCount": "0",
    "modCount": "21",
    "themeCount": "0",
    "originalAppCount": "0",
    "toolkitCount": "0",
    "scriptCount": "0",
    "sOffCount": "0",
    "recoveryCount": "0",
    "score": "687",
    "rank": "1 out of 122"
}
```

here is my parser class.

```
public class JSONParser1 {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser1() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}}
```

here I am just trying to  grab one of the values.

```
public class GetScore extends Activity {


private static String url = "http://example.com"


private static String TAG_NAME = "forumName";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.getscore);

    JSONParser1 jParser1 = new JSONParser1();
    JSONObject json = jParser1.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        json = new JSONObject(TAG_NAME);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  //get nickname
   try {
    json.getString("forumName");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
  ///.... get other value for object
}   
}
```

also How would i tie this to a resourse ID? 
any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class GetScore extends Activity {

private static String url = "http://example.com"
private static String TAG_NAME = "forumName";
private JSONParser1 jParser1 ;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.getscore);

    jParser1 = new JSONParser1();
    new GetJSONTask().execute(url);


}


    class GetJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

       private Exception exception;





protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {
        JSONParser1 jParser = new JSONParser1();
        return jParser.getJSONFromUrl(urls[0]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}




protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    // do all the parsing here:

    //get nickname
    try {
        // You then reset the same variable here
        // the previous object is now lost, or if it throws an exception,
        // the previously set value remains (whether null or not)
        json = new JSONObject(TAG_NAME);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // This object could easily be null, or could be valid if the previous
    // call failed
    try {
        json.getString("forumName");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}}}
```

Comment: getting fc. uncaught exception

Comment: Is your `GetJSONTask` an inner class of the `activity`?

Comment: yes it is . it is in GetScore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is happening because you are trying to perform network operations on the UI thread. You need to use a background thread for network operations.

Use an `AsyncTask` as follows:

```
public class GetScore extends Activity {

    private static String url = "http://example.com"
    private static String TAG_NAME = "forumName";
    private JSONParser1 jParser1 ;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.getscore);

        jParser1 = new JSONParser1();
        new GetJSONTask().execute(url);

        // do not parse here..
        ...
        ...
    }
    ...
    ...

 class GetJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    private Exception exception;

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            JSONParser1 jParser = new JSONParser1();
            return jParser.getJSONFromUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        // do all the parsing here:

        try {
            String forumName = json.getString("forumName");
            Log.i("POST FORUM NAME:", forumName);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } 
 }
}
```

Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Added a simple log option in the `onPostExecute()` method and it shows the name of the forum as expected.

[image]

Comment: as in run in background? can you provide an example? ive tried numerous ways with no luck.

Comment: Yes updating my answer in a bit

Comment: i just updated what i did to get eclipse to accept the code. see above. thats throwing the errors

Comment: ok it doesnt fc butim getting an orange error that forumName cant be converted to an object. json type mismatch

Comment: updated answer.. removed some unnecessary code. I think you are new to programming..

Comment: it still needs the parse class though. that inactivated it. nowit just loads the layout with no connection to json

Comment: The above code should work `99%`.. do a log to see if the json is returned.. are you printing or showing the value somewhere?

Comment: no i was just seeing if it would show in the log. i havent set an id to my layout. i used ListAdapter for my array and that works great. not sure how to tie it to my layout here. it isnt showing in the log. there is no json activity.

Comment: the example just before this one that you wrote showed log activity.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Nor do I see any logging code. Maybe you should post the whole class in 1 piece of code above.

Comment: in the last class i posted above that is everything. that is the example you gave me that is showing up in the log orange. it doesnt fc but it shows json activity in the log. the error is cannot be converted to json object

Comment: Please remove `json = new JSONObject(TAG_NAME);` it is causing the problem.. I already mentioned it to you

Comment: yes i did that earlier and that removes all json activity. that is neccassary

Comment: I just copied the same code and made it run on my machine. Look at the screenshot.. it works. I attached the debugger also, the entire json is fetched beautifully. I am pretty sure that my method works and the problem is at your end. If you are not convinced, then I don't think I can help you anymore.

Comment: ok ill accept your answer. i dont get it. im using your code. thanks for your help.

Comment: just not sure how to tie this to my xml.

Comment: thank you. i updated my answer with the layout view.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer, but this seems suspect:

```
JSONParser1 jParser1 = new JSONParser1();
JSONObject json = jParser1.getJSONFromUrl(url); 
// you get a JSON object from the URL
// you never actually use the value you get from the web page    

try {
    // You then reset the same variable here
    // the previous object is now lost, or if it throws an exception,
    // the previously set value remains (whether null or not)
    json = new JSONObject(TAG_NAME); 
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// This object could easily be null, or could be valid if the previous
// call failed
try {
    json.getString("forumName");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have no idea what is going wrong, but it looks like you are having a NullPointerException, or at least it is the guilty culprit without extra knowledge. You should probably take some time to learn the proper way to deal with exceptions. Your current means of just printing the stack trace is *not* correct.

You need to look at your code, and make sure you know all of the possible paths that it could take, including exceptions. Remember when we have exceptions floating around, the code path is not linear anymore.

I can't find a good article on the subject of handling exceptions, I personally learnt from Joshua Bloch's [Effective Java](http://www.amazon.ca/Effective-Java-Edition-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683) and I **highly** recommend reading it to improve your code.

Comment: Well, I think my answer is wrong, but at the same time, hopefully you find it useful, I'll leave it here. :3

Answer (score 0):

so i added this to my layout this way. thank you Amulya for your help

```
class GetJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {



    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
        setContentView(R.layout.getscore2);


        try {
        JSONParser1 jParser = new JSONParser1();
        return jParser.getJSONFromUrl(urls[0]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    // do all the parsing here:

    try {
        String forumName = json.getString("forumName");
        final TextView id1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.forumUser);
        id1.setText(forumName);


        Log.i("POST FORUM NAME:", forumName);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I see. Good your problem is resolved. What I don't understand is why you unmarked my answer? It is the closest to correct answer to your problem and will guide others who have the same problem

Comment: i had  acceoted your answer a while ago

Comment: you were a huge help and I don't have any memory of unmarking your answer. If I did I apologize. In fact you helped me figure out the last big hurdle of my application.

Comment: Its fine. Right now the other answer is marked as correct answer.. So I was just asking in case there was a problem with my answer.. cheers!

Comment: I'm seeing it marked as answered. when you say other answer I don't see that marked. are you saying your answer still isn't marked?